# Finding out an average in python

Tags: python, equation

I'm reading from a .txt file and have four scores for each person, i need to find out how to take the scores from each line and find the average for each person.

```
s={}
results= open("surf.txt")
for line in results:
  (s['Name'], s['scoreOne'], s['scoreTwo'], s['scoreThree'], s['scoreFour']) =line.split(";")
```

That seems like all the code that's needed to figure this out.

surf.txt contains:

```
Johnny;8.65;7.32;7.81;9.12
Juan;9.12;8.45;8.80;5.60
Joseph;8.45;9.00;9.12;9.13
Stacey;7.81;8.33;9.00;8.10 
(...)
```

Comment: put the contents of the text file "surf.txt" so that we can see the format. Is it really just rows with four numbers each?

Comment: Johnny;8.65;7.32;7.81;9.12
Juan;9.12;8.45;8.80;5.60
Joseph;8.45;9.00;9.12;9.13
Stacey;7.81;8.33;9.00;8.10  
Aideen;8.05;7.55;6.90;8.25
Zack;7.21;6.80;9.90;8.20
Aaron;8.31;8.56;8.34;8.70

Comment: each is in its own line and I'm not fimiliar with averages in python I'm a first semester programming student

Comment: you don't need to be familiar with "averages in Python" you need to know what "average" means - it is the sum of the elements divided by the number of elements. That is not a Python concept.

Comment: For my curiosity :) Where do you study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file has the following format:

```
john; 1; 2; 3; 4
pete; 5; 4; 3; 2
joan; 9; 8; 7; 6
```

Then you can simply:

```
with open('surf.txt', 'rb') as fp:
 for line in fp.readlines():
  tokens = line.strip().split(';') # this creates a list of strings
  name = tokens[0] # extract the first (left-most) string (the name)
  nums = [float(k) for k in tokens[1:]] # convert strings to floats
  mean = sum(nums) / len(nums) # compute the arithmetic mean
  print "%s has a mean of %f" % (name, mean) # print the result
```

Notice that this example would NOT work if the person had more than one name: it assumes that there is only ONE column for the name, and the remaining columns can be converted to floats.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
separator = ";"
inputFile = "input.txt"

with open(inputFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(separator)
        name = values[0]
        scores = map(float, values[1:])
        avg = sum(scores) / len(scores)
        print name, avg
```

Input:

```
Maciej;5;10;15;50
John;15;8;10;14
Mike;5;5;5;5
```

Output:

```
Maciej 20.0
John 11.75
Mike 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the result list with `[1:]`

```
for line in results:
    scores = line.split(';')[1:]
    scores = map(float, scores) # Conversion to float
    average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
```

that's also more general, because you won't depend on number of scores, just reject the first element :)

Comment: `scores = map(lambda x: float(x), scores)` is a convoluted way of saying `scores = map(float, scores)`.

Answer (score 0):

file **cici.csv**

```
Johnny;8.65;   7.32;7.81;9.12 
    Juan;9.12;8.45;8.80;5.60 ;  12.455   ; 2
Joseph Maria y Borbon;8.45;9.00;9.12;9.13 
Stacey      ;7.81    ;8.10
```

code

```
import csv

rid = csv.reader(open('cici.csv','rb'),delimiter=(';'))
av = dict( (row[0].strip(),sum(map(float,row[1:]))/(len(row)-1)) for row in rid)
print av
```

result

```
{'Joseph Maria y Borbon': 8.925, 'Juan': 7.7375, 'Stacey': 7.955, 'Johnny': 8.225}
```